# How to get AWS WAF Classic IP Set's ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

### Where I'll use the ARN

I want to use this ARN at a policy, like below.

```
  "Action": [
                "waf-regional:Get*",
                "waf-regional:List*",
                "waf:Get*",
                "waf:List*
            ],
            "Resource": "arn-that-i-need"
```

### What I've Done

- There is no column for ARN in AWS WAF Classic IP Set Console.
  [image: Console UI Image]
- There is no ARN output in [`aws` cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/waf/get-ip-set.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it on [aws waf classic docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-waf-api-permissions-ref.html), apparently you can see resources' arn formats on permission page of a service.

- For Global:  `arn:aws:waf::<root-account-id>:ipset/<ip-set-id>`
- For Regional: `arn:aws:waf-regional:<region>:<account-id>:ipset/<ip-set-id>`